# Bootstrap3 and FlexBox, to have a 100% height div with 2 columns, one of them scrollable

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I'd like to have a page with a DIV 100% height, with 2 responsive columns. The one on the right should be fixed, no scrolling (as a menu). The one on the right should be scrollable, leaving the left-column independent. I am using Bootstrap 3 to make columns responsive

```
______________________________
|           |                |
|           |                |
|           |                |
|           |   y-scroll     |
|           |                |
| no scroll |                |
| vertical  |                |
| centering |                |
|           |                |
|           |                |
|           |                |
|           |                |
------------------------------
```

=== UPDATE ======

This is my 2nd attempt:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div style="display:flex; height:100px; min-height:0; min-height: 100%; width:100%;">
    <div class="row">
         <!-- left -->
        <div class="col-md-2">
              <div style="flex-direction:column; background-color:red;   display:flex;  height:100%;  justify-content: center;">
               <h1 style="color:white;"> I should be fixed and centered</h1>
              </div>
        </div>
         

          <!-- right -->  
         <div class="col-md-10">       
          <div style="flex-direction:column;  flex:1; max-height:100%; overflow-y: scroll; background-color:green;">
            <h1  style="color:white; margin-bottom:600px;"> I should be > 100% height, and scrollable</h1>
              <h1  style="color:white; margin-bottom:600px;"> I should be > 100% height, and scrollable</h1>
          </div>
        </div>        
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Combining Bootstrap 3 (which is based on `float`) and Flexbox is a bad idea. Instead use Bootstrap 4 (based on Flexbox)

Comment: thank you, on my next update I'll use Bootstrap 4. I need this trick fast for just one page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve most of what you want without using Bootstrap or jQuery at all and just using Flex.

Take a look at this code which is close to what you need, hopefully it helps you

```
<h2 class="text-center">2 responsive columns, 1 fixed 1 not</h2>
<div style="display:flex; height:100px; min-height:0; min-height: 100%">
  <!-- left -->
  <div style="flex-direction:column; background-color:red;">
   <h1 style="color:white;"> I should be fixed and centered</h1>
  </div>
  <div style="flex-direction:column;  flex:1; height: 400px; max-height:100%; overflow-y: scroll; background-color:green;">
    <h1  style="color:white;"> I should be > 100% height, and scrollable</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need Bootstrap for the responsiveness, so on mobile I can hide the left column. Anyway, I've just tried your version integrating Bootstrap, and seems working! Thanks

Comment: Is it cross-browser?

Comment: sorry but it's not working as expected... I've put a new version runnable on codepen in my question text

Comment: This will work in browsers where flex is supported. There is a website you can use to check that called 'caniuse.com'

You can use bootstrap if you want but you don't need it for responsiveness.

You can use a CSS media query to do that instead. That's all that Bootstrap does, wrap media queries for you. 

My solution will work but you will have to play with the heights. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is simple way to obtain this but it´s not the ultimate solution.

I think the h2 tag which tells us what you want to obtain could be removed.

At first i´ve removed everything in your code that´s not really needed:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>


        <!-- left -->
        <div class="col-md-4">

               <h1 style="color:white;"> I should be fixed and centered</h1>



        </div>


        <!-- right -->
        <div class="col-md-8" style="background-color:green;">

                 <h1  style="color:white;"> I should be > 100% height, and scrollable</h1>


    </div>    

</body>
</html>
```

The next step was to give both classes a fixed position, 
one left and one right.

Here comes the quick and dirty solution while the "left div" is 
declared with "overflow:hidden" and the "right div" with "overlflow : auto".

```
* {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
}
body {
color : #000;
font-family : verdana, sans-serif;
}
p {
padding : 1%;
}
.col-md-4 {
position : fixed;
left : 0;
top : 0;
width : 30%;
height : 100%;
background : #ccc;
overflow : hidden;
}
.col-md-8 {
position : fixed;
right : 0;
top : 0;
width : 70%;
height : 100%;
overflow : auto;
}
```

Here is a fiddle which proves that this solution still works:
https://jsfiddle.net/Thorske/5tqLpfjy/1/

And a screenshot of a local test that this won´t generate two scrollbars:
[image: Screenshot1]

And another to prove that "everthing" that should and should not scroll,
as wanted:
[image: screenshot2]

But i´ve to admit that this is not the best way to obtain this.

**Edit**

I´ve updated the fiddle to even make this example on a simple way responsiv
and the content of the left div vertical centered.

The changed html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>


        <!-- left -->
        <div class="col-md-4">

               <h1 style="color:white;"> I should be fixed and centered</h1>



        </div>


        <!-- right -->
        <div class="col-md-8" style="background-color:green;">

                 <h1  style="color:white;"> I should be > 100% height, and scrollable</h1>

    </div>    


 </body>
 </html>
```

The changed css:

```
* {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
}
body {
color : #000;
font-family : verdana, sans-serif;
}
p {
padding : 1%;
}

@media screen and (min-width:1024px) {
.col-md-4 {
position : fixed;
left : 0;
top : 0;
width : 30%;
height : 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
text-align : center;
justify-content: center;
background : #ccc;
overflow : hidden;
}
.col-md-8 {
position : fixed;
right : 0;
top : 0;
width : 70%;
height : 100%;
overflow : auto;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width:1023px) {
.col-md-4 {
float : left;
width : 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
text-align : center;
justify-content: center;
background : #ccc;
overflow : hidden;
}
.col-md-8 {
float : left;
width : 100%;
}
}
```

It may be only an example but it still works fine, 
i´ve not really change that much to make things work.

The media queries will do thier work but i would recommend 
to define them in a more "specific" way.

To align everything on the left i´ve added only 4 line of code:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
text-align : center;
justify-content: center;
```

The updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Thorske/5tqLpfjy/11/

Comment: in this way, I can't get the vertical center on the left column, and I don't have responsiveness

Comment: I´ve updated the fiddle to match the centered content and also added a simple example with media queries.